# Instantiate COM object that doesn't have ProgID by class/interface name

Tags: python, pywin32, pythoncom

`pywin32` docs for client-side COM show this basic way to instantiate COM objects:

```
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("<ProgID>")
```

I'm trying to work with `PersistentZoneIdentifier` akin to [Manipulating the zone identifier to specify where a file was download from – The Old New Thing - MSDN blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131104-00/?p=2753). That class, as the registry at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0968e258-16c7-4dba-aa86-462dd61e31a3}` shows, doesn't have a corresponding `ProgID`.

I see that there's an underlying [`pythoncom.CoCreateInstance`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/pythoncom__CoCreateInstance_meth.html) function that accepts a `CLSID` to instantiate and an `IID` to apparently query from it.

But this is inconvenient because I have to use unintelligible GUIDs instead of human-readable names.

---

The question is:

- Is there a stock way in `pywin32`/underlying WinAPI to look up the aforementioned GUIDs by names? (do not suggest searching the registry by hand)
- Or maybe some other way to instantiate that object with names?

---

<sub>What I tried and failed: `win32com.client.IDispatch(<class/interface name>)`, `pythoncom.IID(<class/interface name>)`. Also looked through the Net, MSDN and PyWin32 docs, of course.</sub>

Comment: Assign the unintelligible GUID to a nicely-named variable, which is basically what a ProgID does for you.

Comment: @MarkTolonen That's an interesting question actually: are ProgIDs guaranteed to be unique like GIUDs? If yes, then how is this facilitated? There is no "practical uniqueness" algorithm behind their "generation", after all.

Comment: [A programmatic identifier (ProgID) is a registry entry that can be associated with a CLSID. Like the CLSID, the ProgID identifies a class but with less precision because it is not guaranteed to be globally unique.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542719(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no, and can't be any, "stock mechanism" to instantiate a class/query an interface by its name because their names aren't guaranteed to be unique, unlike GUIDs.